# Reorder legend without changing order of points on plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I keep running into this issue in ggplot2, perhaps someone can help me.

I have a plot where the order of the variables in the legend is in reverse order to how they are displayed on the plot.

For example:

```
df=data.frame(
 mean=runif(9,2,3),
 Cat1=rep(c("A","B","C"),3),
 Cat2=rep(c("X","Y","Z"),each=3))

dodge=position_dodge(width=1)
ggplot(df,aes(x=Cat1,y=mean,color=Cat2))+
 geom_point(aes(shape=Cat2),size=4,position=dodge)+
 scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue","black"))+
 scale_shape_manual(values=c(16:19))+
 coord_flip()
```

produces:

[image: example]

So the points are displayed on the plot as Cat2=Z,Y, then X (black diamonds, blue triangle, red circle) but in the legend they are displayed as Cat2=X, Y, then Z (red circle, blue triangle, black diamond).

How can I reverse the order of the legend without shifting the points on the plot?  Reordering the factor produces the opposite problem (points on the plot are reversed).

Thanks!

Comment: For now, probably there is no easy way. The next version may have an option to reverse the legend order, though.

Comment: Hmm, that stinks.  Good to know.  Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @hadley yes, yes. why did I miss it???

Comment: @jslefche so you can easily modify it. sorry for the misleading.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, do I set the breaks for scale_x_discrete("Cat2")?

Answer (score 6):

To flesh out Hadley's comment, we would do something like this:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Cat1,y=mean,color=Cat2))+
 geom_point(aes(shape=Cat2),size=4,position=dodge)+
 scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue","black"),breaks = c('Z','Y','X'))+
 scale_shape_manual(values=c(16:19),breaks = c('Z','Y','X'))+
 coord_flip()
```

[image]

Note that we had to set the breaks in *both* scales. If we did just one, they wouldn't match, and ggplot would split them into two legends, rather than merging them.

Comment: If you have several manual scales, e.g. `scale_fill_manual` , `scale_color_manual` and `scale_shape_manual` and you wish to change the labels, you need to supply the same labels to all of them, which can be tedious (say you have 6 variables with 6 long explanatory labels). There is no other way, is there?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand what you want to achieve, this simple manipulation does the trick for me:

1. define a Cat2 as a factor (with the levels in the adequate order) and
2. chage the order of colours and shapes to match the levels order (in the scale_manual commands)

Here is the code to do it:

```
library(ggplot2)

df=data.frame(
    mean=runif(9,2,3),
    Cat1=rep(c("A","B","C"),3),
    Cat2=factor(rep(c("X","Y","Z"),each=3), levels=c('Z', 'Y', 'X'))) 

dodge=position_dodge(width=1)
ggplot(df,aes(x=Cat1,y=mean,color=Cat2))+
    geom_point(aes(shape=Cat2),size=4,position=dodge)+
    scale_color_manual(values=c("black","blue","red"))+
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(18:16))+
    coord_flip()
```

Comment: Alas, as I buried at the end of my question, reversing the factor reverses the legend but also reverses the points on the plot (red circle is now first).  I want to preserve the order of points on the plot but reverse the legend.  I had used your solution and just copied the legend onto the first plot.  Inelegant, but it will have to do.  Thanks for the insight all the same!